# Passing Value to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a jQuery function, but the alert function displays [object Object]. The check value works, but not the passed id value.

Here's the call to the function taken from the html output:

```
<td class="myGroups">
    <input class="chkSubscribed" type="checkbox" onclick="UpdateSubscription(2)" name="subscribed">
</td>
```

Here's the javascsript function:

```
$(".chkSubscribed").change(function(id) {
    alert(id);
    var chkd=0;
    var groupid=id;
    if (this.checked) { chkd=1; }
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"resources/updateSubscribe.php",
        data: { group_id: groupid, checkval: chkd },
        success: function(){
        alert("Account updated!" + "chkval=" + chkd + " id=" + groupid);                }
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

Either you want to call a function or you want to use the change event.

If you want to call a function create a function as follows:

```
function moo(id) {
    //code here
}
```

If you want to do it using the change event you can give your input an id of the number you want as follows:

```
<input id="2" class="chkSubscribed" type="checkbox" name="subscribed">
```

And then your javascript should look as follows:

```
$(".chkSubscribed").change(function() {
    id=this.id;
    //and the rest of the code as you wrote
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different issues at play here.

1. Using `alert()` for debugging. This is almost always worse than using `console.log()`. Everything passed to `alert` is converted to a string, which is why you see `"[object Object]"` instead of something useful. Switch to `console.log()` and you'll see something meaningful.
2. jQuery event callbacks are passed a [jQuery `event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). *That* object is what `id` is set to.
3. The inline `onclick` handler has **absolutely nothing** to do with the `change` handler that you've bound with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery function [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) will pass the event object, not the id of the changed object - you treat it as if it was the id currently.